# Add token in header of api call Redux Saga

Tags: reactjs, api, redux, token, redux-saga

How can I add token in the header of api call using redux saga?

`const response = yield call(post, url, data.payload);`

Answer (score 1):

the first arg `post` is your api call function, redux-saga is just execute this function and get response, so you should add token into your api call function not redux-saga.

which api util are you using? these two are more popular api call libraries.

1. using fetch

```
fetch(
  'url',
  {
    ...
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ /* your token string */
    }
  }
);
```

2. using axios

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_IP,
    timeout: 60000,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+ /* your token string */}
});
```

Comment: I'm  using call() fuction to post and get data from api.
`import {postutil} from '../../utils/httpService'`

Comment: add token into your `postUtil`